# How to log/ find every single method call on the main thread automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is there a way to follow a chain every function call on the  main thread without having to manually write a log statement in every method?

For example, I would love to see (automatically)

`- SomeViewController:viewDidAppear(...)`
`- SomeModel:loadModel(...)`
`- SomeService:findModel(...)`

You might look at this and say "oh shoot, I shouldn't be finding the model on the main thread."

Of course this presumes it's filtering out all the 
framework calls and only displaying the user's library of code. It's basically a means for me to find out where it's not smart for me to be calling things on the main thread.

Possible?